# Nebula NatTable persist state

Tags: filter, persistence, nattable, nebula

We have used NatTable in one of our applications. The nat table is used to load the contents from an XML file and has sorting and filtering functions implemented. I read a post about Persistence in Nat table http://www.eclipse.org/nattable/documentation.php?page=persistence.

This topic is new to me so I am not able to change our implementation successfully to save the filter row state on close of table and load the filter row state (as saved earlier) when the table is loaded again later. Can you please tell me the steps to be followed for this operation. I referred the PersistentNatExample.

There is a class in our application which extends FilterRowHeaderComposite. I have overridden the saveState() method in this class to store the properties object to file system. When i debugged the code and when it reaches the saveState() method in FilterRowDataProvider class the "filterIndexToObjectMap" object is empty. I suspect this is why the filter state is not saved and loaded as expected. Have I missed anything?

Comment: The link you mention contains the explanation and the sample. You just need to take care of the Properties object in some way. Typically storing it to the file system. As the information is already available the question is not clear to me.

Comment: Thanks. I referred the example and did some changes in my code but still it is not working. I have updated my post with some queries.

Comment: Sorry but if you override internal methods to do things that should not be done there I can't help.